# Android LatLng parsing

Tags: android, dictionary, google-maps-markers, geocoding

I want to display adress on marker clicked on the android map. I used GeoCoder for getting adress but OnMapLongClick function doesn't have lat,long parameters. It's parameter is (LatLng latlng). My code below ;

```
@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {


    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(
            getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);

        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            for (int index = 0;
                 index < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); index++)
                filterAddress += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(index) + " ";


        }
    }catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e2) {
        // TODO: handle exception

        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(filterAddress)).showInfoWindow();


    markerClicked = false;
}
```

How can I parse or how can i convert latlng object to lat, lng parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way extract `Latitude` and `Longitude` from `LatLng`

```
@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {

Double lat=latLng.latitude;
Double longi=latLng.longitude;
.........
.......... 
//do your job
}
```

Comment: in addition, another problem is when i long click to add marker, old previous marker is still shown. i want to hide previous marker. how can i do it? @SimplePlan

Comment: no you can not hide it but instead of u can clear map by using `map.clear();` or u can remove particular Marker by using `marker.remove();`

Answer (score 1):

With a small google search, [`LatLng`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng.html) class

Use public fields `latitude` and `longitude` to read the two values.

```
List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `latlng.latitude` and `latlng.longitude` to get lat and lng parameters.